# Sync Thunderbird tasks and calendar between two Ubuntu 16.04 computers without cloud?

Tags: 16.04, thunderbird, sync

Is there a way to synchronise Thunderbird tasks and calendars between two Ubuntu 16.04 computers without cloud?  Ideally, automated would be nice.

As of now, what I do currently is just export tasks and events to ics, send it over network and then import on second computer and vice versa.

Comment: You can use `unison` and create and create a profile to update the folders you want.  You can then make `unison` to run as a regular task using `cron`.   Unison works through `ssh` so you would need to set that up as well.

Comment: would there be any problems using the same Thunderbird folder for two pc's?

Comment: Every day I synchronise my files with my laptop and desktop PCs.  In my case, I want Thunderbird (and other software) to be and behave exactly the same in both places.  For this I synchronise all files and most of my settings, including .thunderbird folder (but I do not synchronise any cache or temporary foldes files to save time. I have been doing this for years now and I have absolutely no issues.  In your case, if you want things to be different except for the tasks and calendars, all you need to do is find the folder where those files reside and synchronise only that folder.

Comment: There is one key thing here when using unison: if I have been using my laptop and want to switch to use to my desktop, I first synchronise and then I open Tbird on the other computer.  If you open Tbird on both computers and then try to synchronise there will likely be conflicts.